# Update From & Select Into To ignore Duplicate

Tags: sql-server

i wrote this Sp to insert/update UserExams table which contain (UserID,ExamID,studentMark) 
I need to add new mark for the student who has no mark
and update student mark if it already exists
i use Split Function which return table contain (ID,vItem)

I dont now where is the error here can anybody help me, Please
there error i got is : The multi-part identifier "UserExams.UserID" could not be bound.

```
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[InsertUserMarks]
(    
@pSemesterID int,    
@pCourseID int,    
@pExamID int,    
@pClassID int,     
@pUserID varchar(8000),
@pMarks varchar(8000)     
)    
as    
--save the values of MaxMark To check if there is any Mark higher than the full mark if so then stop execution    
DECLARE @vTestMaxMark decimal(5,2)    
SET @vTestMaxMark = (select ExamMark from Exams where ExamID=@pExamID)    


IF EXISTS (select 'true' from Split(@pMarks,',') WHERE vItem>@vTestMaxMark)    
begin    
print('Operation cannot complete; there are one or more Mark ABOVE the Max value')    
return
end    


            update UserExams 
            Set StudentMark=MA.vItem
            from split(@pUserID,',') us
            inner join split(@pMarks,',') ma on us.ID = ma.id
            where UserExams.UserID=US.vItem
            and UserExams.ExamID=@pExamID


            --Insert
            insert into UserExams   
            select us.vItem,1,ma.vItem,system_user,getdate(),null,null from
            split(@pUserID,',') us
            inner join split(@pMarks,',') ma on us.ID = ma.id
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 'True'
            FROM split(@pUserID,',') us
            inner join split(@pMarks,',') ma on us.ID = ma.id
            where UserExams.UserID=US.vItem
            and UserExams.ExamID=@pExamID

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be at the very bottom of the query. You have an insert into with a sub query that references the UserExams table, but that sub query doesn't include UserExams in its FROM clauses, which it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would make use of **Merge statement** in this proc, All for record Existence in big table can be very costly.

 Merge statement will check the for the record existence and making use of **WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE** and **WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT**  will make your code a lot simpler and easier to understand and maintain.